# dynamically increase and decrease the relative layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

dynamically increase and decrease the relative layout , i want to shrink the size of relative layout when recycler view popup from bottom of screen and after using it agian the screen will return into normal size(in recycler view im sung icons to put on relative view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:layout_weight="1">

////////tool bar
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_weight="1">

         <com.cmlibrary.CircleMenu
            android:id="@+id/circle_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"

            />
     </RelativeLayout>
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to show and hide the visibility of views as required. But if you want to increase and decrease the size then below code will help you.

```
 private void layoutParams() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
    /* When recyclerView shows*/
    layoutParams.height = layoutParams.height - params.height;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    /* When recyclerView hidden*/
    layoutParams.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: how to show the recycler view on top of relative layout and after using the recycler view how to hide ,i m using icons on recycler view and after setting the icons how to hide that view ,      Thanks for result it is woking as expected